# Translate GeoTIFF to mbtiles success but failed to load on QGIS

Tags: python, gdal, mbtiles

I try to convert GeoTIFF data to mbtiles format using `gdal_translate` on Python console. The process was succeed but when the mbtiles was loaded on the canvas it's just blank. Any idea?

Here is the original GeoTIFF on canvas
[image]

Here is the mbtiles on the canvas
[image]

And here is my code:

```
import gdal

gdal.UseExceptions()
raslayer = "C:/PROJECT/2020/DERAWAN.tif"
rasterout ="C:/PROJECT/2020/derawan8.mbtiles"

ds = gdal.Open(raslayer)
ds = gdal.Translate(rasterout, ds, format="MBTILES")
ds = None
```

And I also try this using commandline on ubuntu, here my script :

```
gdal_translate Derawan.tif Derawan.mbtiles -of MBTILES
gdaladdo -r nearest Derawan.mbtiles 2 4 8 16
```

But it's still return blank when loaded on QGIS Cannvas.
Any ideas why the mbtiles couldn't load successfully?

Comment: How does it go with the command line gdal_translate?

Comment: @user30184 I also try using command gdal_translate then gdaladdo on ubuntu ( I add it at the question)